# Saving emails in .msg format using SMTP client in .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, client

I need to save emails that are being sent from my .Net web C# application using SMTP client in .msg format. I have set delivery method as SpecifiedPickupDirectory. This does not work as SSL is enabled and disabling it cannot be done. Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you say that disabling SSL "cannot be done."?  EnableSsl is a property on the client, off by default.  If you are in control of the code, as is apparently the case, since you say "I have set delivery method...", why can't you remove the line of code that is enabling SSL?

Comment: Thanks.. But on disabling SSL , it creates an .eml file.How to create a .msg file?

Comment: See if this article can help you: https://weblogs.asp.net/darrensim/creating-an-outlook-message-file-with-c

Comment: I would also suggest that you consider if you truly need to have the .msg extension, which is an Outlook-specific format. .eml, on the other hand, is a plain-text format that can be opened by many (all?) email clients, including Outlook itself. Thus it is more portable. And of course you can inspect its contents using just a text editor, which makes debugging easier.